# Uploading image using api in node express using multer package

Tags: node.js, express, image-uploading, multer

This question has been asked before. But as I have failed to get solution for my problem, I am asking again.

I am trying to upload image for a property using multer package as form-data so I can store other data and path of image in the database. I am using node express.

My api--

```
      api.post('/service', upload.single('servicesImage'),
          (req, res,  next) => {
              console.log(req.file);
              Company.find({ domain: req.headers.domain }, 
                  (err, company) => {
                     const servicecontent = new Servicecontent({
                     description: req.body.description,
                     created_at: Date.now(),
                     created_by: req.body.user_id,
                     company_domain: req.headers.domain,
                     company_uuid: company[0].uuid,
                     image: req.file.path,
                     })
                     servicecontent.save(err => {
                         console.log(err);
                     });
           res.json({ status: "success" });
           });
         });
```

I watched a tutorial, and from that I added these codes to upload image and other options--

```
   const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, './src/uploads/');
      },
      filename: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString()+ file.originalname);
      },
   });

   const upload = multer({storage: storage, limits:{
      fileSize: 1024*1024*5
   },
      fileFilter: fileFilter
   });

   const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) =>{
      if(file.mimetype=== 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype=== 'image/png'){
         cb(null,true);
      }else{
         cb(null,false);
      }
   };
```

Now when I send data and image through **Postman** , from `console.log(req.file)`
I get valid data as I saw from the tutorial. Api responds without any errror, and in database I can see all datas are stored including image path. But the issue I am facing is that in `src/upload` folder is empty, no image is uploaded.

**N.B.** -- I am using linux 18.04 Os, and fs package can't be installed. So `src/upload` folder wasn't creating when I were sending req, so I created this directory from folder.

**Edit:** I can upload image with this code now, I don't exactly know why this wasn't working earlier. I should close this question, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can upload image with this code now, I don't exactly know why this wasn't working earlier. I should close this question, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to store images.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
   destination: function (req, file, cb) {
     cb(null, 'uploads/')

   },
   filename: function (req, file, cb) {
       console.log(file);
     cb(null, makeid(3) + file.originalname)
   }
 })

 var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
  `
```